# Access array inside of array in javascript for google maps api

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to access an array inside of an array in order to combine coordinates with a marker for google maps.
The `path()` function expects an array of `google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng)` to draw a `polyline`. The `google.maps.Marker` object(?) expects coordinates, some other stuff, and a text string as title. My idea now was to have a two dimensional array containing the coordinates and the title string. However, I can't make the path function accept the coordinates from my two dimensional array.

```
var destinations = [
  [new google.maps.LatLng(52.238942,7.349558),'Somewhere'],
  [new google.maps.LatLng(25.073858,55.2298444), 'Dubai'],
  [new google.maps.LatLng(13.7246005,100.6331108), 'Bangkok'],
];

var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: destinations[0],
  geodesic: true,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 2
});
```

Thanks a lot,
Klayman

Comment: [The examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple) for the Polylines don't seem to indicate you can actually pass it an array of arrays. It looks like it wants just an array of LatLng objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using LatLng constructors, you can pass that polyline an array of LatLngLiterals, which can have extra keys at will.

```
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            zoom: 3,
            center: {lat: 20, lng: 63}
        });

        var destinations = [
            {lat:52.238942, lng:7.349558,    title:'Somewhere'},
            {lat:25.073858, lng:55.2298444,  title: 'Dubai'},
            {lat:13.7246005,lng:100.6331108, title: 'Bangkok'},
        ];

        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: destinations,
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          map:map
        });
```

By the way, you were passing the first destination as path, but instead you should pass the whole collection (a polyline needs an array of vertexes). Second, your polyline was missing the map parameter for it to be drawn on the map.